# Hammer.js sets focus on input underneath an overlay when clicking on overlay and removing it

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, hammer.js

When I put a fixed overlay over an input, listen to the Hammer.js *tap* event on the overlay and remove it when tapped the input underneath gets focused.

This does not happen on a PC, I have tested this with an iPad but it should work with other iOS (or any touch) based device.

Example: http://codepen.io/RobFox/pen/HFrfs

How can I prevent the input from getting focus?

Answer (score 0):

Calling

```
event.gesture.preventDefault();
```

seems to do the trick along with the latest version of Hammer (v1.0.6dev - 2013-11-05).

http://jsfiddle.net/yYJ4P

**UPDATE**

This fixes the issue on iOS, but not on pre KitKat (which replaces WebView with Chrome and does work OK) Android devices.